# MySQL DB Implemented Using Java/JDBC - Basic Design Query

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, database-design

I have to implement a basic MySQL database in Java (Chess League).  It has 4 tables:

```
PLAYER(PlayerName, DateOfBirth, FIDERating, FIDETitle, ClubName∗)
CLUB(ClubName, Address, DateFormed)
GAME(GameID, DatePlayed, BoardNum, Score, MatchID∗, WhitePlayer,
BlackPlayer)
MATCH(MatchID, MatchDate, Venue, Score, WinningClub, LosingClub)
```

I must implement stored procedures to query the database and include appropriate triggers.

I assume my lecturer gives credit for correct object-oriented design principles as I am using Java.

I am having trouble applying these principles to the creation of a database, should I have a class to create the database and tables, then have one further class to store methods to execute the stored procedures and triggers?  I also intend on making a menu class to handle user selection such as selecting queries (stored procedures).  If there was any guidance on using OOD principles with this task, I'd be (more than) happy to hear it.

One class I have so far to create the database and 1 table.  I am not sure if it adheres to correct design principles.  I have followed tutorials which provide sample code, but place it all in a main method.  I certainly don't want to do this.

```
public class ImplementDatabase 
{
    private String user;    // MySQL user account 
    private String pass;    // MySQL account password
    private String host;    // MySQL host     
    Connection conn;        // application needs to communicate with JDBC driver
    Statement st;           // issuing commands against the connection is reqiured
    Scanner keyboard;       // get input from user

    /* When instantiated the JDBC driver attempts to load */
    public ImplementDatabase()
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Could not load the driver");
        }
    }

    public void createDatabase() 
    {
        try 
        {   
            this.readLogin();
            // prompts user to enter login info to console
            this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection
            ("jdbc:mysql://"+host+":3306", user, pass);
            this.st = this.conn.createStatement();
            int Result = this.st.executeUpdate("CREATE DATABASE ChessLeague");
            System.out.println("You are successfully connected to the "
                    + "Chess League Database");
        } 

        catch (SQLException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(ImplementDatabase.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            System.out.println("Please check that the login information you"
                    + "have provided is correct");
        }
    }


    public void createPlayerTable()
    {
        try 
        {
            this.st = this.conn.createStatement();
            this.st.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PLAYER"
                    + "(PlayerName VARCHAR(30)PRIMARY KEY,"
                    + "DateOfBirth DATE,"
                    + "FIDERating tinyint,"
                    + "ClubName FOREIGN KEY fk_club(Clubname) REFERENCES club(ClubName)");                    
                    // Create Actor table
        } 
        catch (SQLException ex) 
        {
            Logger.getLogger(ImplementDatabase.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }        
    }

    private void readLogin()
    {
        this.keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter username:");
        this.user = keyboard.next();
        System.out.println("\nPlease enter password:");
        this.pass = keyboard.next();
        System.out.println("\nPlease enter host or ip address:");  
        this.host = keyboard.next();
    }
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is for fixing issues with code.  This question is off topic since it's way too broad (and also somewhat opinion based).  If you have some code to share, perhaps people could give you specific pointers

Comment: I see, I had an aching feeling I should have posted in Software Engineering.  I have just one class of code, I'm not sure if it adheres to OOD.  I will edit my post to include it.  I understand if this post must be closed.

Comment: Java is very OO.  SQL is very non-OO.  Where a different thinking cap for each.

Comment: OK, I see what you mean!  Will keep in mind.

Comment: Please come up with a more descriptive title for your questions; a title should get people interested, and as it stands it is almost only tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for architecture of java program that involves database connectivity, then DAO is the right pattern. Try this http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/dataaccessobject-138824.html

Comment: Brilliant, that is exactly the type of thing I was looking for.  As usual, I'll need to study it a fair bit as it's quite advanced (I'm a year 2 computing science student), but I'm up for a challenge, and it's the correct architecture standards I wanted.